# Spring Boot caching with ContentVersionStrategy prohibits resource compression with gzip

Tags: java, spring-boot, gzip, etag

We have a Spring Boot web application with Thymeleaf. 
Inside the HTML templates, we reference some static resources, e.g. `/src/main/resources/static/js/main.js` via `<script defer th:src="@{/js/main.js}"></script>`.

To allow browsers to cache the static resources for multiple visits of our website, we enable content versioning:

```
spring.resources:
    chain:
      strategy.content:
        enabled: true
        paths: /**
    cache.cachecontrol.max-age: 365d
```

This all works fine and we get the resource with its MD5 hash appended to the filename (e.g. `/main-d9f17fd70ee583fef4acf26dd331b8ab.js`).

To further decrease traffic volume, we now want to enable resource compression with gzip:

```
server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: application/javascript,and-some-others
    min-response-size: 1024
```

When requesting the (versioned) resource with header `Accept-Encoding='gzip'`, we don't get a response with `Content-Encoding='gzip'`. Hence, resource compression seems not to work in conjunction with content versioning.

If we disable content versioning, resource compression works just fine:  the `Content-Encoding='gzip'` header is set for the (now non-versioned) resource.

So we digged into the inners of Spring and found the following:

1. `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.VersionResourceResolver#getResponseHeaders` always sets the (strong) ETag header:

```
public HttpHeaders getResponseHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = (this.original instanceof HttpResource ?
            ((HttpResource) this.original).getResponseHeaders() : new HttpHeaders());
    headers.setETag("\"" + this.version + "\"");
    return headers;
}
```

2. `org.apache.coyote.CompressionConfig#useCompression` disables compression, if there is a strong ETag:

```
public boolean useCompression(Request request, Response response) {
    ...
    if (noCompressionStrongETag) {
        String eTag = responseHeaders.getHeader("ETag");
        if (eTag != null && !eTag.trim().startsWith("W/")) {
            // Has an ETag that doesn't start with "W/..." so it must be a
            // strong ETag
            return false;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You could set `noCompressionStrongETag` to false, but this is deprecated and will be removed with Tomcat 10...

To demonstrate the issue, I created an [example project in Github](https://github.com/luddwichr/etag-and-gzip) with three passing tests and one failing test that shows where our expectations are not met...

Do you have an idea how to solve this contradiction? Are we doing something badly wrong?

Comment: If I understand correctly, response with strong ETag should not be gzipped purely because it is a byte-to-byte comparison it represents. IMO if ETag would be generated from a gzipped content then it should be allowed, otherwise changing compression algorithm does not invalidate ETag which is "wrong". Maybe there is a way to use weak ETags?

Comment: [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources) mention usage of `EncodedResourceResolver` which must be before `VersionResourceResolver` which means you need to compress before applying a version I think.

Comment: Interestingly enough `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` sorts those in correct order as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L530)

Comment: Yepp, I also saw that. However, `EncodedResourceResolver` seems to only be applied to resources that are already compressed, i.e. have a file ending ".gz" or" ".br". I would rather not provide the javascript files as .gz files since that would break clients not supporting gzip...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is now tracked in [Spring's Github repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24898). Currently the idea is to switch from strong ETags to weak ETags in Spring's `VersionResourceResolver`.

**Update**: the issue is resolved with Spring Boot 2.4, which comes with Spring 5.3. containing the fix.

A contributer highlighted in the issue that the current behavior is linked to a fix in Tomcat addressed [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63932). There, it was concluded that response compression violates the meaning of strong ETags and is thus a bug. Therefore, Tomcat only applies compression if no or only a weak ETag header is present (which is consistent with my observations described in the SO question).